# Не запускается окно

Tags: python, tkinter

Я начал делать утилиту для проверки заряда и сигнализации при низком её количестви появлялся сигнал, но почему то окно не появляется, почему?

```
from tkinter import *
from psutil import sensors_battery
from time import sleep


root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x300')
label= Entry(width=5)
def battery():
    a = sensors_battery()
    percent_of_baterry = str(a.percent)
    label.delete(0, END)
    label.config(text=percent_of_baterry)
    sleep(5)
while True:
    battery()


root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что эта строка `root.mainloop()` не выполняется из-за бесконечно цикла

Comment: в ткинтере есть классная штука root.after(милисекунды,функция) .  и слип уберите

Comment: @timur, я проверил, нет

Comment: @Интик ```from tkinter import *
from psutil import sensors_battery
from time import sleep


root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x300')

def battery():
 root.after(500, battery)
 a = sensors_battery()
 percent_of_baterry = str(a.percent)
 label.delete(0, END)
 label['text']=percent_of_baterry

label= Entry(width=40)
label.pack()
 
while True:
 battery() 

print('добрий день')

root.mainloop()```вот так?

Comment: не успел ответ написать.from tkinter import *
from psutil import sensors_battery

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('300x300')
label= Entry(width=5)
def battery():
    a = sensors_battery()
    percent_of_baterry = str(a.percent)
    label.delete(0, END)
    label.config(text=percent_of_baterry
                 
    root.after(5000,battery)
battery()

root.mainloop()